# PySpark replace Map Key-Value with empty string for null keys

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I did A groupby on my column and for some reasons my dataframe looks like this

```
ID           col
1            [item1 -> 2, -> 3, item3 -> 4, -> 5]
2            [item2 -> 1, -> 7, item3 -> 2, -> 7]
```

I want to remove the KV that have no keys or null key

I want something like this

```
ID           col
1            [item1 -> 2, item3 -> 4, -> 5]
2            [item2 -> 1, item3 -> 2, -> 7]
```

My Approach

```
dsNew = ds.withColumn("col", expr("map_filter(col, (k, v) ->  k != '')"))
```

But the map_filter method is not available in PySpark

Answer (score 1):

[`map_filter()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_filter.html) is available from version 3.1.0. However your column needs to be of `map` type, like this for example:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- data: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Then you could do the following:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F

df = df.withColumn("filtered_data", F.map_filter("data", lambda k, v: k != ""))
```